# how to get the number of days between the current date and the date supplied jquery

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate the number of days between the date provided and the current date.
I am using the following javascript, but i am getting wrong results.

```
function getcabin(saildates) {
    var d = new Date();

    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var day = d.getDate();

    var output = d.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    alert(daydiff(parseDate(output), parseDate(saildates)));
}
function parseDate(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('-')
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
    return (second-first)/(1000*60*60*24)
}
```

Can anyone please point out the mistake or how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are using the format `yyyy-mm-dd`:

```
var output = d.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day;
```

Here you are parsing it as `mm-dd-yyyy`:

```
return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
```

To format the date so that it fits for the parser:

```
var output = month + '-' + day + '-' d.getFullYear();
```

If you want to parse it as `yyyy-mm-dd`:

```
return new Date(mdy[0], mdy[1]-1, mdy[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply i corrected my mistake but it is not working. I have created a fiddle for it pls check it jsfiddle.net/v2wvF/8

Comment: @asifa: That outputs `2` when I try it. What output do you expect?

Comment: Have u checked the fiddle. I am getting 420

Comment: @asifa: Yes, that's where I got the outout `2`. I retested it in Firefox, IE, Chrome, Safari and Opera, and get the same everywhere.

Comment: But why i am getting 420 even in my browser and my program. Even in the fiddle i am getting 420. Any ideas why???

Comment: There was some problem with my system datetime.Thats solved now. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for new Date is

> new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond])

A side from that, you're adding 1 to month in getcabin but -1 to year in parseDate.

Answer (score 0):

in your code there is mistake in passing parameter in new Date function.

Syntax is:

```
    new Date(year,month,day[,hour,minute,second,millisecond]);
```

Modified code:

```
function getcabin(saildates)
{
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var day = d.getDate();

    var output = d.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    alert(daydiff(parseDate(output), parseDate(saildates)));
}
function parseDate(str)
{
    var mdy = str.split('-')
    return new Date(mdy[0], mdy[1]-1, mdy[2]);
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
    return (second-first)/(1000*60*60*24)
}
getcabin("2012-10-8")
​
```

This will alerts correct value of day.

Comment: I am not getting the correct answer it is alerting 420 whereas it should alert just 2. I have created a fiddle for it pls check it http://jsfiddle.net/v2wvF/8/

Comment: I have checked on Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE. i am getting correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this function

```
function getDayDiff(date) {
     return parseInt(((new Date()) - date)/(1000*60*60*24))
}
```

so if you try to find the day difference from the First day of the year

```
getDayDiff(new Date(2012,0,1))
```

you get the result as `279` days